# Interpolation - function interpn

Tags: python-3.x

How to use function internp? [I look at manual, but I am confused.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html)

```
print('A = ',type(A))
print('B = ',type(B))
print('C = ',type(C))
print('Mat = ',type(Mat))


A =  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
B =  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
C =  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Mat =  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>



Ex=interp.interpn((A,B,C),np.squeeze(Mat[0,:,:,:]),A[0],A[1],A[2], 'linear')
```

I have an error:

```
ValueError: interpn only understands the methods 'linear', 'nearest', and 'splinef2d'. You provided [[ -1.00000000e-03  -1.00000000e-03  -1.00000000e-03  -1.00000000e-03
   -1.00000000e-03  -1.00000000e-03  -1.00000000e-03  -1.00000000e-03
   -1.00000000e-03  -1.00000000e-03  -1.00000000e-03  -1.00000000e-03
```

Comment: you have passed more arguments. interpolation points is one argument. you have provided ```,A[0],A[1],A[2]```

Comment: There should be only one number with 1 dimension? In Matlab are given components of vectors, but in python not? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html#d117e742267

Comment: When I use one number, there is an error: ValueError: The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending